# How to compute the confidence interval of a correlation function

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

What is the best way to compute confidence intervals of a (cross) correlation (function value at lag time $\tau$) $c(\tau)$?
Typically one estimates the value $\hat{c}(\tau)$ but the question is what is the confidence interval associated with this estimate?

I found the following approaches during my search:

1. Fisher's z transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation can be used like in https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/04_correlation_2016_cost_symposium_fkuo_tagged.pdf page 8-10 to compute a confidence interval for a correlation coefficient
2. Block Bootstraping resampling of correlated time series
3. Bartletts Formula as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlogram#Statistical_inference_with_correlograms and  "Testing autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation: Asymptotic methods versus resampling techniques" https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED610086.pdf (equation 1)

While I was able to find a discussion comparing Fisher's transform to Block-Bootstrap ("Speaking Stata: Correlation with Confidence, or Fisher's z revisited
" https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X0800800307 ) and a discussion comparing Bartletts Formula to Block-Bootstrap ("Testing autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation: Asymptotic methods versus resampling techniques" https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/bmsp.12109 ), I was unable to find an apporach comparing Fisher's transform to Bartlett's Formula.

I currently do not know what is the best way to compute the confidence intervals for the correlation coefficient estimates.

PS: I also found this website which might be interesting for some of you: https://quantdare.com/bootstrapping-time-series-data/